# rj45 - simulate interface "link up" state

Tags: ethernet, cable, layer1

My colleague told me today he saw some sort of RJ45 dongle that intended to simulate a "link up" state for the connected interface (for testing purposes).

Can this be achieved by doing a specific wiring? (i have RJ45 crimping tools)

For instance:

[image]

Comment: I think a simple cable tester would do the trick for you.

Comment: [What is the purpose of the Microsoft Loopback Adapter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021415/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-microsoft-loopback-adapter)  and  [interface range {fastethernet interfacenumber - interfacenumber | gigabitethernet interfacenumber - interfacenumber | loopback number](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/interface/command/reference/finter_r/irfinter.html)

Comment: A loopback *interface* is not the same as a loopback *cable* (aka "plug")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never have tried make that kind of connector manually, but theoretically is possible. You only have to connect RX to TX and TX to RX to create a loop in the RJ45. I know that kind connector usually are use to test E1 cards to auto test it.

Answer (score 5):

[@Roid's theory](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/33505/15827) did the trick. Here's the proof of concept:

### Requirements

- Short ethernet cable (~2 inch)
- RJ45 connector
- RJ45 Crimper

[image]

Peel the cable's coating

[image]

Wire RX to TX

[image]

Crimp it!

[image]

### Result

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will work for 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX because they use one pair to send and one pair to receive, but not for 1000BASE-T because it uses all four pairs to both send and receive, and it will fall back to 100BASE-TX if it can't communicate bidirectionally on all four pairs.

Comment: I've seen line and wiring techs with these in their bag. One of them called it his "Sanity Check Plug."

Comment: Could you please post which pins need to be connected - from the pic it could be 1-8 downwards or 8-1 downwards.